# Extract values from appsetting.json doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i have an issue about extract value from appsetting.json

> appsetting.json

```
"Negozi": {
"PerPage": 10,
"Order": {
  "By": "Name",
  "Ascending": false,
  "Allow": ["Nome", "Citta"]
  }
}
```

> Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         //useless code for this question
          ...

         //Options
        services.Configure<NegoziOptions>(configuration.GetSection("Negozi"));
     
    }
```

> NegoziOptions.cs

```
public class NegoziOptions
{
    public int PerPage { get; set; }

    public NegoziOrderOptions Order { get; set; }
}

public class NegoziOrderOptions{
    public string By { get; set; }

    public bool Ascending { get; set; }

    public string Allow { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Then I want to extract data and this is my method

```
public class EfCoreNegoziService : INegoziService
{
    private readonly C3PAWMDbContext dbContext;
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<NegoziOptions> negozioOptions;

    public EfCoreNegoziService(C3PAWMDbContext dbContext, IOptionsMonitor<NegoziOptions> negozioOptions)
    {
        this.negozioOptions = negozioOptions;
        this.dbContext = dbContext;

    }



public async Task<List<NegozioViewModel>> GetNegoziAsync(string search, int page)
    {
        search = search ?? "";

        page = Math.Max(1, page);
        int limit = negozioOptions.CurrentValue.PerPage;
        int offset = (page - 1) * limit;

        /*
         Other code
        */
  }
```

Im trying to debug but this is equals to 0

> int limit = negozioOptions.CurrentValue.PerPage;

I have already take data from appsetting.json like ConnectionsStrings and it works fine but i can't understand why I can't extract from Negozi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Negozi` property in `appsettings.json` format is not match with `NegoziOptions` class.

`Allow` property in `appsettings.json` is **array** of **strings** and `Allow` property in `NegoziOrderOptions` class is **string**.

You should change type of `Allow` to array of string in `NegoziOrderOptions`.

Your `NegoziOptions` class should be like this

```cs
public class NegoziOptions
{
    public int PerPage { get; set; }

    public NegoziOrderOptions Order { get; set; }
}

public class NegoziOrderOptions
{
    public string By { get; set; }

    public bool Ascending { get; set; }

    public string[] Allow { get; set; }
}
```

your `appsettings.json` should be like this

```json
{
  "Negozi": {
    "PerPage": 10,
    "Order": {
      "By": "Name",
      "Ascending": false,
      "Allow": [
        "Nome",
        "Citta"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And Configure method:

```cs
services.Configure<NegoziOptions>(a => configuration.GetSection("Negozi").Bind(a));
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed. The issue was the string[]. It was a mistake when I mapped the json class into the Option class